# Get all markers from GeoJSon map data and store them in an array?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geojson

I was wondering if my "logic" is correct.
I am loading different datas on a map using a geojson object using **addGeoJson**.
With this method markers as well as polygons, are drawn automatically, which is good but how to access to them from outside the map ?

There no problems at all, I just wanted to get all markers for all my geometry type "Point" to store them in an array, in order to be able to trigger them from outside the map and launch an infowindow for exemple.

I found nothing in documentation, so I used the code below to remove the markers then create the same markers and add them to **markers** array.

```
// add GeoJson datas
map.data.addGeoJson($.parseJSON(Config.polygon));

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
      markers = [];

  map.data.forEach(function(feature){
    if(feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Polygon'){
      feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng){
        bounds.extend(latlng);
      });
    }else if(feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point'){
      var LatLng = feature.getGeometry().get(),
          id = feature.getProperty('id'),
          icon = Config.templateDirectoryUri+feature.getProperty('icon'),
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            id: id,
            icon: icon,
          });
      markers[id] = marker;

      // load infowindow
      IDV.mapInfoWindowHTML(feature, map, marker);
      // remove previous markers from map.data
      map.data.remove(feature);
    }
  });

  // bounds gmap window to polygons boundaries
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Afterwards no problem to trigger my markers from my ".property" class using jQuery and data attribute.

```
$('.property').on('click', function () {
  if($(this).data('markerid') !== 0){
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('markerid')], 'click');
  }
})
.mouseenter(function() {
  if($(this).data('markerid') !== 0){
    markers[$(this).data('markerid')].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
})
.mouseleave(function() {
  if($(this).data('markerid') !== 0){
    markers[$(this).data('markerid')].setAnimation(null);
  }
});
```

My question is simple, does someone know **a more efficient way** to store markers directly form map.data, instead of having to add them again (new google.maps.Marker) and delete the previous one... it works well anyway like this.

Thanks

Comment: Does `map.data.addGeoJson($.parseJSON(Config.polygon));` add just one polygon or does it add all your polygons and markers?

Comment: Hi @Dana, it adds several polygons and points, as feature type Polygon and feature type Point

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @lavor no I kept my first logic to manage this...